# Seed executables randomization outside of code

Tags: random, clock

We have put in place a features test framework which consists in running our code against some third partie`s pre-existing software. We do so periodically and compare the results with expected results (same as unit tests, but the tests themselves are more complex than unit tests).

The 3rd partie's software se use are pre-compiled executable (there are actually 2 executables called MoveIt (within the ROS robotic framework) and Coppelia Sim (robotics simulator), very certainly coded in C++. However for the sake of this question I do not think these details really matter. As I want to compare the results over and over again, the output of the test framework need to be deterministic. Though the pre-compiled executables use random numbers generation.

In order to get a deterministic results out the 3rd parties executable's random number generators. I am looking for a way to seed the executable externally (i.e. not from the code to which I do not have full access). I know most random number generations are seeded against the computer clock, hence I was thinking that **if I could fool the executables and have them believe they are executed from a different time clock than the computer's, I could indeed seed these executable externally.**

What do you think? Any idea to seed executables from outside the code?

NOTE : we actually have access to MoveIt' source code which we could recompile (though it is certainly rather heavy and a daunting task to turn such a heavy and unknown codebase into a deterministic behavior) but we do not have access to CoppeliaSim' source code - hence we cannot recompile (and thus we cannot seed from within the code).

Comment: Yes fake clock or fake OS random number generator `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534466/how-to-correctly-fake-time I think this may not work, you will need to have a fixed time (clock stops ticking), so will only work if the program does not need to measure time. If time needs to tick, then variations in process scheduling may get in the way.

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181448/creating-a-device-similar-to-dev-random-from-a-script combined with bind mount, and namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you need to use a clock which is fixed.  Hopefully the code that you are using works on a Monotonic clock, which may get its value from the CPU rather than the system clock (wall-time).

A fairly simple way of testing this is to write a bash script which performs the following steps:

1. Sets your system clock
2. Runs the software

Try this a few times and see what the results are.  If you are able to match the results between each run of the script, then you may have a working, and quite easy, solution.  If for whatever reason the developer decided to seed on something like the millisecond value, you may be less fortunate.

This script could look like:

```
#! /bin/bash
date --set="8 FEB 2021 10:00:00"
./your-program-here
```